# Append one ore more rows from Excel to existing SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have imported an Excel table into SQL Server 2016 Express and made a table using the import wizard.

Now when I update my Excel sheet, e.g add one ore more row to it, I also want to update my SQL Server table, that means, adding the one ore more rows to the  table as well. What's the easiest way to do this? In an "append" rows manner. I don't want to add the whole Excel sheet again..

Answer (score 1):

You asked for the easiest solution.  Since you are already comfortable using the wizard it would seem to me that the easiest way is to import the "updated" Excel sheet / file into SQL Server Express using the wizard as well. Yet, import it into a new table (without removing the old one).

Afterwards, insert new rows or update the existing records on the SQL Server with a simple SQL `MERGE` statement. Afterwards, you can drop / delete the imported table again (because the existing table has been updated).

While I do not know your tables the following SQL code sample shows a simple merge on a basic customer table where `tblCustomers` would be the exiting table (to be updated / insert new rows) and `tblCustomersNEW` would be the new import (which will be deleted again once the update / append is complete):

```
merge dbo.tblCustomers as target
using dbo.tblCustomersNEW as source
on source.ID = target.ID
when matched then
    update set target.Name = source.Name,
               target.Country = source.Country
when not matched by target then
    insert (Name, Country)
    values (
            source.Name,
            source.Country
           );
```

Note, that the `MERGE` statement [requires a semicolon at the end](http://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/rules-of-sql-formatting-terminating-sql-statements-with-semicolons/) similar to `CTE` requiring a semicolon before you start `; With myTable as...`.

For more information on the `MERGE` statement you might want to read the following on article on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

Comment: but then the problem persists, its even more complicated,  I could overwrite the table simply instead... isnt there a linked_server option to link my excel sheet with the server and update it with a stored procedure?

Comment: Interesting that you consider this to be easier. Of course this is also possible. But then the SQL server will need to have access to that Excel file. Hence, you'll need to setup the permissions correctly and have a file-share which is accessible to the SQL and any computer working on the Excel file. Afterwards you could import the file with `SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
  'Excel 12.0 Xml; HDR=YES;
   Database=X:\DataFiles\CustomersData.xlsx',
   [Customers$]);`